# Stuck with prisma1 schema design and data migration

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I have two tables, service and location. I want to insert ids of the multiple locations in the array format in service table, field name is "disable Locations". Each service have some disable location.

I have designed schema as below, and it doesn't return any error when I deploy schema changes.

```
type Location {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  image: String!
  currency : String!
  lpf: Float!  
  email: String!
}

type Service {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  lastSlot: String
  disableLocations: [Location!]
  startPrice: Json
  hasNote: Int! @default(value: 1)
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}
```

Now, below is the mutation I have created to insert my JSON data to Prisma DB.

```
 axios({
    url: HOST_GRAPHQL,
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        query: `
            mutation createService($name: String!, $lastSlot: String!, $disableLocations: [LocationCreateManyInput!]!) {
                createService(
                data: {
                    name: $name,
                    lastSlot: $lastSlot,
                    disableLocations :$disableLocations
                },
                ){
                    name,
                    lastSlot,
                    disableLocations { 
                        id
                    }
                }
            }`,
        variables: {
            name: ele.name,
            lastSlot: ele.lastSlot,
            disableLocations: ele.disableLocations,
        }
    }
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result, "result-----");
});
```

When I am trying to insert some sample data as you can see below, it returns error in disable location field.
Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Painting",
    "lastSlot": "16:00",
    "disableLocations": [
        "ckfoo7rwflsbk09996zw7micu",
        "ckfo6i9cxk85d09994ggr2xny",
        "ckfondzstlq960999ktpwo9ux"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Waterproofing",
    "lastSlot": "15:00",
    "disableLocations": [
        "ckfoo7rwflsbk09996zw7micu",
        "ckfondzstlq960999ktpwo9ux"
    ]
  }
]
```

Returns error like this

```
[
      {
        "message": "Variable '$disableLocations' of type '[LocationCreateManyInput!]!' used in position expecting type '[LocationCreateInput!]'. (line 2, column 84):\n                        mutation createService($name: String!, $lastSlot: String!, $disableLocations: [LocationCreateManyInput!]!) {\n                                                                                   ^\n (line 8, column 45):\n                                    create: $disableLocations\n                                            ^",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 84
          },
          {
            "line": 8,
            "column": 45
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I have tried type "LocationCreateInput" for disableLocations as mentioned in the error, but it doesn't work.

Can you guys please help me with array insertion, how can i insert multiple location ids in the service.disableLocations field.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're trying to create a `service` Record  and connect it to existing `location` records through the `disableLocations` field.

I think you have the syntax incorrect. `disableLocations` should be of type `LocationCreateManyInput` as you are trying to connect to multiple `location` records. You should be using the `connect` API.

Here is the query you need to do

```js
axios({
    url: HOST_GRAPHQL,
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        query: `
            mutation createService($name: String!, $lastSlot: String!) {
                createService(
                data: {
                    name: $name,
                    lastSlot: $lastSlot,
                    disableLocations :{
                        connect:[{
                          id: "ckvks95gb007l08355f17ebno"  // id of existing `location` records
                        },
                        {
                          id: "ckvksb0nr008o08353n8foccn"
                        }]
                      }
                },
                ){
                    name,
                    lastSlot
                }
            }`,
        variables: {
            name: ele.name,
            lastSlot: ele.lastSlot,

        }
    }
})
```

I removed the `disableLocation` as a variable and inlined the data to make the syntax a bit more clear. But it would work just as well as a variable.

I have two additional suggestions, I'd love to know your thoughts:

1. Prisma1 is outdated and no longer in development. Unless you have a strong reason for using prisma1, I would strongly suggest [migrating to the latest version](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrade-from-prisma-1/how-to-upgrade). I'd love to know your use-case and what you're using Prisma 1 for!
2. You're using axios to interact with the Prisma 1 API. However, the recommended way would be to use the [prisma client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-client-lib).